# Add Images dynamically in fillable pdf using iTextSharp

Tags: asp.net, .net, pdf, itext

I have an interactive PDF form. I can fill out this form, but I also want to add one image at bottom of the PDF dynamically. Images vary according to logged in user.

How i can add an image?  I'm using following code to create a data table:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
String pdfPath1 = Server.MapPath("pdfs\\transmittal2.pdf");
if (File.Exists(pdfPath1)) {
    dt = objClsTransmittal.GetTransmittal(jobid, cid);
    String comment = "Correspondence generated for " + dt.Rows[0]["Recipient"].ToString();
    var formfield = PDFHelper.GetFormFieldNames(pdfPath1);
    formfield["Enter Date"] = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
    formfield["Contact Name"] = dt.Rows[0]["Recipient"].ToString();
    formfield["Enter Project Name"] = dt.Rows[0]"PropertyAddress"].ToString();
    formfield["Enter Project Number"] = dt.Rows[0]["JobID"].ToString();
    formfield["Company Name"] = dt.Rows[0]["Company"].ToString();
    formfield["Company address"] = dt.Rows[0]["Address1"].ToString();
    formfield["City State ZIP"] = dt.Rows[0]["address2"].ToString();
    formfield["User Name"] = dt.Rows[0]["Recipient"].ToString();
    formfield["Combo Box11"] = "Select from List";    
    var pdfcontent = PDFHelper.GeneratePDF(pdfPath1, formfield);
    PDFHelper.ReturnPDF(pdfcontent, "Transmittal.pdf");
}
```

I'm looking forward to replies.

**Editor's note:** I've edited this question for language. Maybe I should also have removed the code snippet as it's an irrelevant part of the code. The relevant part is in the `GeneratePDF()` method that isn't shown anywhere. In my answer, I added a couple of lines that indicate what's probably done in `GeneratePDF()`. (Bruno Lowagie)

Comment: By "fill able pdf" do you really merely mean that it has form fields to fill in or do you actually mean that in addition the PDF with those fill-ins can be saved in Adobe Reader? I ask because some people tend to mean the latter (even though "Reader-enabled PDF" is more apropos here).

Comment: yes it has form fields to fill.

Comment: Then Bruno's answer shows you the way. Whether `stamper.GetUnderContent` or `stamper.GetOverContent` serves your needs best, you have to decide based on your use case.

Comment: @mkl thanks, Its working as required, :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the [StampStationery](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter06/StampStationery.cs) example.

As you're filling out a form, I guess you already have something like this:

```
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms)) {           
    AcroFields form = stamper.AcroFields;
    form.SetField(key, value);
}
```

where `key` and `value` are the keys and values from your code snippet.

What you now want is something like this:

```
PdfContentByte background = stamper.GetUnderContent(pagenumber);
background.AddImage(image, x, y);
```

where `pagenumber` is the number of the page where you want to add the image, `image` is the Image instance, and `x` and `y` are the coordinates. Note that the `y` value at the bottom is lowat than the `y` value at the top. The actual coordinates depend on the `CropBox` value of your form. If there is no `CropBox`, use the `MediaBox` value.

Note that using `GetUnderContent()` means you're adding the image under the existing content. Use `GetOverContent()` if the image can cover the existing content.